# What is the difference between warnen and verwarnen?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Im Fußball verwarnt der Schiedsrichter die Spieler bei einem Foul mit gelber Karte.
Die Wettervorhersage warnte vor Gewittern mit Hagel.

Comment: warnen = to warn, verwarnen = to caution

Comment: @TorstenLink Bei "caution" und "warn" überschneiden sich die Bedeutungen und beides könnte je nach Kontext sowohl mit "warnen" oder "verwarnen" übersetzt werden. Eindeutiger: warnen = to alert, verwarnen = to reprimand.

Comment: Ändert natürlich nichts daran, dass der Fragesteller auch erstmal ein Wörterbuch hätte benutzen können..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By "verwarnen", a (mostly formal) warning is given, it might include, as in soccer, an indicator (red card), or a penalty fee or similar.
By "warnen", you normally mean a kind of information on critical things (such as bad wheather, or that the teacher tells you not to talk otherwise you will get (in the future) a "Verwarnung".